# winapi destroyWindow() immediately exits my program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

Okay, i can understand if the function would return an error or throw an exception, but for some reason my call to DestroyWindow literally exits the program at that point. Like with the actual exit() function changing my program flow. The documentation mentions nothing like this and i have no means of figuring out what is going on since i get no error code. Has anyone ever encountered something like this?

I'm doing quite a bit more with this object than using winapi, so ignore the rest of it. What else could be wrong here?

SYNC_WinSystem.h

```
#ifndef SYNC_WINSYSTEM_H
#define SYNC_WINSYSTEM_H

#include "SYNC_ISystem.h"

#include <Windows.h>
#include <array>
#include "SYNC_Winput.h"
#include "SYNC_IRenderer.h"
#include "SYNC_D3D11Renderer.h"

#define FULL_SCREEN true

// SYNC_WinSystem
class SYNC_WinSystem : public SYNC_ISystem
{   
public:
    class WindowsContext;

    SYNC_WinSystem();

    virtual long Initialize(InitializeContext *);
    virtual void Init_Loop();
    virtual void Shutdown();

    virtual long MakeDirectory(std::string);
    virtual bool CreateSkin(std::string, std::string, SYNC::ISkin *&);
    virtual ISound * CreateSound();

    LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

private:
    virtual long InitializeWindows();
    virtual bool Frame();
    virtual void ShutdownWindows();

private:
    SYNC_Winput m_Input;

private:
    std::shared_ptr<SYNC_IRenderer> m_Graphics;
    HINSTANCE m_hinstance;
    HWND m_hwnd;
    int m_screenWidth;
    int m_screenHeight;
    std::string m_WindowName;
};

// SYNC_WinSystem::WindowsContext
class SYNC_WinSystem::WindowsContext : public SYNC_ISystem::InitializeContext
{
public:
    WindowsContext();
    std::string Type();

    HINSTANCE m_hinstance;
    std::string m_WindowName;

private:
    const static std::string m_Identifier;
};


#endif
```

SYNC_WinSystem.cpp

```
#include "SYNC_WinSystem.h"

// SYNC_WinSystem definitions
SYNC_WinSystem * g_windows;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

SYNC_WinSystem::SYNC_WinSystem()
    : m_Graphics(new SYNC_D3D11Renderer)
{
    m_hinstance = nullptr;
    m_hwnd = nullptr;
    m_screenWidth = 0;
    m_screenHeight = 0;
}

long SYNC_WinSystem::Initialize(InitializeContext  * context)
{
    long result = 0;
    char errors[256];
    WindowsContext * cContext;
    if(context->Type() == "WindowsContext")
        cContext = static_cast<WindowsContext *>(context);
    else
        return false;

    m_hinstance = cContext->m_hinstance;
    m_WindowName = cContext->m_WindowName;
    g_windows = this;


    result = InitializeWindows();
    if(result)
    {
        sprintf_s(errors, "The Window could not initialize. Windows error code: %i", result);
        MessageBox(NULL, errors, "Error!", MB_OK); 
        return result;
    }

    std::array<std::string, 3> folderNames=
    {{
        "Compiled_Models",
        "Temp_Models",
        "Materials"
    }};

    for(int i = 0; i < (int) folderNames.size(); i++)
    {
        result = MakeDirectory(folderNames[i]);
        if( result && (result != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS))
        {
            sprintf_s(errors, "Error creating directory \" %s \" for system. Windows error code: %i", folderNames[i].c_str(), result);
            MessageBox(NULL, errors, "Error!", MB_OK);
            return result;
        }
        result = 0;
    }

    SYNC_D3D11Renderer::D3D11Context graphicsContext;
    graphicsContext.fullscreen = true;
    graphicsContext.hwnd = m_hwnd;
    graphicsContext.screenDepth = 1000.0f;
    graphicsContext.screenNear = 0.1f;
    graphicsContext.screenWidth = m_screenWidth;
    graphicsContext.screenHeight = m_screenHeight;

    if(!m_Graphics->Initialize(&graphicsContext))
        return false;

    return result;
}

void SYNC_WinSystem::Init_Loop()
{

    MSG msg;
    bool done, result;

    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    done = false;

    while(!done)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if(m_Input.IsKeyPressed(VK_ESCAPE))
        {

            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = Frame();
            if(!result)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }

    }
}

void SYNC_WinSystem::Shutdown()
{
    ShutdownWindows();
}

long SYNC_WinSystem::MakeDirectory(std::string dirName)
{
    DWORD result = 0;
    long returnValue = 0;

    dirName.insert(0, ".\\");
    result = CreateDirectory(dirName.c_str(), NULL);

    if(result == 0)
    {
        returnValue = GetLastError();
    }
    return returnValue;
}

bool SYNC_WinSystem::Frame()
{

    if(!m_Graphics->Frame())
        return false;

    return true;
}

long SYNC_WinSystem::InitializeWindows()
{
    DWORD result = 0;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;
    int posX, posY;

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = m_hinstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hIconSm = wc.hIcon;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = m_WindowName.c_str();
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);



    if(RegisterClassEx(&wc) == 0)
    {
        result = GetLastError();
        return result;
    } 

    m_screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    m_screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    if(FULL_SCREEN)
    {
        memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));
        dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = (unsigned long) m_screenWidth;
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = (unsigned long) m_screenHeight;
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = 32;
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN);
        posX = posY = 0;

        m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, 
                             m_WindowName.c_str(), 
                             m_WindowName.c_str(),
                             WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP,
                             posX, posY, m_screenWidth, m_screenHeight,
                             NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL);

    }
    else
    {
        m_screenWidth = 800;
        m_screenHeight = 600;

        posX = ((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2) - (m_screenWidth/2));
        posY = ((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2) - (m_screenHeight/2));

        m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, 
                             m_WindowName.c_str(), 
                             m_WindowName.c_str(),
                             WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP,
                             posX, posY, m_screenWidth, m_screenHeight,
                             NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL);
    }



    if(!m_hwnd)
    {
        result = GetLastError();
        return result;
    }

    ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(m_hwnd);
    SetFocus(m_hwnd);

    return result;
}

void SYNC_WinSystem::ShutdownWindows()
{
    ShowCursor(true);

    if(FULL_SCREEN)
    {
        ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0);
    }


    if(DestroyWindow(m_hwnd) == 0)
    {
        char meh[256];
        sprintf(meh, "error: %i" , GetLastError());
        MessageBox(NULL, meh, "error!", MB_OK);
    }

    m_hwnd = NULL;

    UnregisterClass(m_WindowName.c_str(), m_hinstance);
    m_hinstance = NULL;

    g_windows = NULL;

    return;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {

            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        default:
        {
            return g_windows->MessageHandler(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
        }
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK SYNC_WinSystem::MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            m_Input.KeyDown((unsigned int) wparam);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_KEYUP:
        {
            m_Input.KeyDown((unsigned int) wparam);
            return 0;
        }
        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
        }
    }


}

ISound * SYNC_WinSystem::CreateSound()
{
    return nullptr;
}

bool SYNC_WinSystem::CreateSkin(std::string filename, std::string shaderName, SYNC::ISkin *& skin)
{
    if(!m_Graphics->CreateSkin(filename, shaderName, skin))
        return false;

    return true;
}


// SYNC_WinSystem::WindowsContext definitions
const std::string SYNC_WinSystem::WindowsContext::m_Identifier = "WindowsContext";

SYNC_WinSystem::WindowsContext::WindowsContext()
{


}

std::string SYNC_WinSystem::WindowsContext::Type()
{
    return m_Identifier;
}
```

quick explanation of how i do this. window handle and hinstance have private members in the object, and during the Initialize() and InitializeWindows() functions, the window class and window itself is created. The windows procedure is defined below as a global function, because you can't use a member function as a windows procedure. I dodge around this by making a global pointer (gasp) at the top, and assigning it to the this pointer of the system, which allows the procedure to call a member function procedure. Still only allows one instance of the system, but that's all i need :. Anywho, during shutdown, ShutdownWindows() is called, which then calls DestroyWindow. It is during this call, that my program simply ends, no error, no exception. MSVC++ express tells me it returns error code 3, but as far as windows error codes, that's just an ERROR_PATH_NOT_FIND which makes no sense in this context. Anyone have a clue?

main.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <Windows.h>

#include "Syncopate.h"
#include "SYNC_WinSystem.h"
using namespace std;

#include "SYNC_Winput.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    //create a new instance of the engine
    std::shared_ptr<SYNC_WinSystem> system( new SYNC_WinSystem);

    // create an init context for this specific derivative of SYNC_ISystem
    SYNC_WinSystem::WindowsContext context;
    context.m_hinstance = hInstance;
    context.m_WindowName = "Syncopate";

    // Initialize the system object. if something goes wrong, return ERROR
    if(system->Initialize(&context))
        return 1;

    SYNC::ISkin * model;

    if(!system->CreateSkin("data.txt", "ColorShader", model))
        return 1;

    system->Init_Loop();

    system->Shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your message loop that will notice a `WM_QUIT` and abort. The "standard" practice for a message loop is to call `GetMessage()` until it fails, which indicates `WM_QUIT`, but you're calling `PeekMessage()` which has no handling for `WM_QUIT` at all. Your message loop only exits when done is true, which will only happen when escape is pressed or your `Frame()` call fails.

As you discovered, the solution was to redesign your loop to properly handle `WM_QUIT` messages and to not call DestroyWindow after the loop has already ended.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be going on is that you handle the `WM_DESTROY` message and explicitly call `PostQuitMessage`. I suspect somewhere that `WM_QUIT` message is being processed and causing an exit of some sort. I'll see if I can find any further information, but that's my understanding so far.

### Rule of Thumb:

When you receive a `WM_CLOSE` message, call `DestroyWindow`. When you receive a `WM_DESTROY` message, call `PostQuitMessage`. Because you are using `PeekMessage`, you will get a message structure for a `WM_QUIT` message. When you find this message, you should end your loop.

Comment: yup, when i call ShutdownWindows() i explicitly call destroyWindow() which is handled and calls PostQuitMessage(0) which posts WM_QUIT, and is supposed to end the message loop and then continue shutting down the rest of my application, but it simply aborts when destroyWindow() is called.

Comment: Is there any parenting of windows going on? Any hooks installed? Can you make sure that your HWND is valid when you call DestroyWindow, just in case? Is this all in a single thread?

Comment: it is all in a single thread, and if you count using the window to display d3d graphics in then yes. Don't know what a hook is so probably not. How might i go about ensuring the HWND is still valid before the call?

Comment: Put a break point where you handle WM_Destroy and also where you call DestroyWindow. Make certain that they are not being hit multiple times.

Comment: okay, because of direct staying in full screen until the end of all the shutdown, i'm unable to see the results of the breakpoint at the destroy window, but i was able to find that the breakpoint at the WM_DESTROY message was only hit once.

Comment: That should make sense. However, I'm concerned that DestroyWindow might be getting called multiple times and, since the window is destroyed after that call, is calling DestroyWindow with an invalid handle. Can you perhaps write to a file or something, so that you don't have to deal with the fullscreen issue? Perhaps play a sound? Something quick and dirty, just to confirm.

Comment: k, i made a quick option to toggle fullscreen, helpful anyway, and the break point revealed something interesting. The first time that it makes it to the destroyWindow call, it says **unused CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated** for the value of m_hwnd . I am positive though that this handle is valid throughout the init_loop because the window opens and i do render to the window. What could this mean?

Comment: My guess? Your window handle is borked. StackOverflow is suggesting we bring this into a chat however, because it's an extended discussion. May want to do that.

Comment: [Chat link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17320/discussion-between-sion-sheevok-and-fatalcatharsis)

Comment: Just an FYI: There's nothing in your message loop that will notice a `WM_QUIT` and abort. The "standard" practice for a message loop is to call `GetMessage()` until it fails, which indicates `WM_QUIT`, but you're calling `PeekMessage()` which has no handling for `WM_QUIT` at all. Your message loop only exits when `done` is true, which will only happen when escape is pressed or your `Frame()` call fails.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter - ...give me 30 minutes, i think i have a plan.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter - Turned out to be much easier than i thought. When you think about what DestroyWindow does, calling it after the message loop has ended makes no sense. Omitting that from shutdown, and then changing the loop to only exit when a quit message is recieved and making all other cases that end the loop simply call PostQuitMessage(0); , and viola, the error has dissappeared. If you could post this as an answer, i would be happy to accept it, with special thanks to Sion for assisting as well.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

IIRC exit code 3 is what you get by calling `abort`.

Anyway,

```
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
```

is very ungood (it terminates your message loop), and most likely the cause of your problems.

Just remove that.

---

Update: since the above recommendation didn't improve things, I suspect that you're calling `DestroyWindow` on an already destroyed window.

As a rule you should only call `DestroyWindow` in response to `WM_CLOSE`. For general windows that's the default handling. There is no indication in the presented code (as I'm writing this) of how your "shutdown" code is called, but due to the identical handling of `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_DESTROY` I suspect that it's a call placed after the message loop.

And in that case it is indeed likely that you're calling `DestroyWindow` on an already destroyed window.

Comment: If I am correct, `WM_CLOSE` is sent when the user clicks the X button, and should call `DestroyWindow` itself. On the other hand, `WM_DESTROY` is sent by `DestroyWindow` and is the message of interest here.

Comment: @AnthonyBurleigh: the default handling of WM_CLOSE for general windows is that DestroyWindow is called; however this isn't done for dialogs.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. -alf - the message loop is the Init-Loop function which is called to start the messaging loop/ rendering loop for both windows and d3d. I have a function in there that exits the loop when escape is pressed. When this loop is exited, would the window be destroyed for some reason? And yes, the shutdown function is called after the message loop has been exited

Comment: You'd better post some code. But first, reduce the problem to a *complete, small program*.